# key check JSONObject org.json.simple in JAVA

Tags: java, json, jsonparser, json-simple

Key convert into `jsonobject` using `org.json.simple`. I have tried a number of ways to did it but all failed

**1st way**

```
JSONObject name1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(key);
```

> error : cannot convert java.lang.string to org.json.simple.json.object

**2nd way**

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject name1 = (JSONObject) parser.parse(key);
```

> error : Unexpected character (N) at position 0.
>       at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Unknown Source)
>       at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(Unknown Source)
>       at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)

**3rd way**

```
Long name1 = Long.valueOf(jsonObject.get(key));
```

> error: The method valueOf(String) in the type Long is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

**4th way**

I used this function:

```
optJSONObject(key)
```

> error:  optJSONObject is undefined for JSONObject

How can I get this to work?

Comment: What exactly is the `key` string? Can you show us the value that `key` holds?

Comment: ``` JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        // get the keys of json object
        Set keys = obj.keySet();
        Iterator iterator = keys.iterator();
        //Iterator iterator = obj.keys();
        String key = null;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            key = (String) iterator.next();```

Comment: in key every iteration can come string , JSONObject , JSONArray

Answer (score 1):

So the JSONObject.get(key) function usually doesn't return a json object itself. But the org.json packet hast accounted for this.
Careful reading from this point since org.json includes 2 JSONObject packages, the org.json.simple and the plain org.json.JSONObject and thus I don't know if this explicitly works in org.json.simple but it's what I do when handling JSONObjects with the org.json package.

```
JSONObject name1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
```

This line does what you want to do there. Try it.

The JSON package brings functions like getInt, getString, getJSONObject for you to specify exactly what type of data you want to get.

Comment: sir i tried this library org.json but by this i got error in parsing because in parsing i used org.json.simple.. then error came org.json.simple cannot parse into org.json
``` Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/Envy/Documents/company.json"));
 
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;```

Comment: ```JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONObject name1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);```
the method getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject

Comment: This is because you defined your JSONObject to be extracted from the library org.json.simple.JSONObject and not org.json.JSONObject. It's a very unclear thing but if you check your references and change them to org.json.JSONObject across the boards you should be fine with this method

Comment: ```JSONParser parser  = new JSONParser();``` this is undefined in  org.json.JSONObject.. how i do it ...using org.json.JSONObject.

Comment: So what does the JSONParser do for you, I couldn't really find anything about it

Comment: Please check the link where it shows how to transform from one class to another using jackson and same can be used to transform the json string to other classes -  https://www.thetechnojournals.com/2019/10/entity-object-conversion-to-dto-object.html

Comment: brother i did successfully but why updation value of key is not reflect in my JSON file ..

Answer (score 0):

This line

> error : Unexpected character (N) at position 0.

in your **2nd way** code fragment / quote kind of states that you're parsing invalid JSON. 
`JSONObject name1 = (JSONObject) parser.parse(key);` the `key` in this line probably contains invalid JSON. That is why the parser throws an exception.

You can try to debug the code and see what the `key` strings look like and you should find out which one (if not all) contain invalid JSON.

I created a minimalistic program which parses a valid `JSONArray` (or a `JSONObject`, if the file contains only a single JSON object) from a file (which you mentioned under @Sepx3's answer). I tried to use names from your code snippets for the relevant code, so that it stays a bit clear.

The content of my `C:/Users/Envy/Documents/company.json` example file:

```
[
  {
    "key": "value"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value1"
  },
  [
    {
      "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
      "key3": "value3"
    }
  ]
]
```

And the code which parses it, stores it into the object and then checks whether a `JSONArray` or a single `JSONObject` has been parsed (in my example it is a `JSONArray`).

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import java.io.FileReader;

public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        Object obj = null;
        try {

            obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/Envy/Documents/company.json"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle possible exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // If the parsed string was a single json object
        if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            // Do something with jsonObject, in this example it prints the content of jsonObject
            System.out.println(jsonObject);

        }
        // Or else if the parsed string was a json array
        else if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;

            // Do something with jsonArray, in this example it prints the content of jsonArray
            System.out.println(jsonArray);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you at least a bit and sets you on the right track.